# Error loading pig script

Tags: apache-pig

I am having difficulty loading data using apache pig script

```
cat data15.txt
1,(2,3)
2,(3,4)


grunt>a = load 'nikhil/data15.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (x:int, y:tuple(y1:int,y2:int));

grunt>dump a;

(1,)

(2,)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Pig not parsing a tuple fully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838408/apache-pig-not-parsing-a-tuple-fully)

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer this 
 
The problem is that the tuple and the other field have the same delimiter as ','. Pig fails to do the schema conversion.
you can try something like this
you need to change the delimiter
1:(5,7,7)
3:(7,9,4)
5:(5,9,7)
and run the pig script as 
`A = load 'file.txt' using PigStorage(':') as (t1:int,t2:tuple(x:int,y:int,z:int));
dump A;`
the output is
(1,(5,7,7))
(3,(7,9,4))
(5,(5,9,7))
you can change the delimiter using sed command in the input file and then load the file.